# Highcharts - What is the equivalent of line-height?

Tags: highcharts

Like when you give enter to go down one line. When I put one text under the other there is no space and it looks like one is on top of the other. 
Here is the code of what we are trying to generate. TIA

```js
$(function () {

    Highcharts.chart('grafica1', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ' '
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null,
            },
            labels: {
                    enabled: false
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:#005eb8">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b>'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Production',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'PACKAGING PAPERS<br>AND BOARDS',
                y: 49,
                color: '#005eb8'
            }, {
                name: 'CASE MATERIALS',
                y: 29.9,
                color: '#fff',
                borderWidth : 2,
                borderColor : '#005eb8'
            }, {
                name: 'OTHER PACKAGING & PAPER',
                y: 14.4,
                color: '#fff',
                borderWidth : 2,
                borderColor : '#005eb8'
            },{
                name: 'WRAPPINGS',
                y: 4.7,
                color: '#fff',
                borderWidth : 2,
                borderColor : '#005eb8'
            }, 
            {
                name: ' ',
                y: 100,
                color: '#fff',
                borderWidth : 0,
                borderColor : '#fff'
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

```css
#grafica2 tspan {
    font-size: 15pt;
    fill: #8cc640;
    font-family: Bebas-Bold;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: That is the same under highcharts' CSS items. Do you have a specific example where you applied this and it did not work?

Comment: You can use useHTML property and use html break line tag. Without html, you can use <tspan> to position text. If you have a specific problem, paste the code or recreate that on jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you both for your reply. We have tried what you said but it doesn't work. Please see the JS code and the CSS code. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code itself instead of the image of the code?

Comment: you can find now the code. Sorry and thanks for your help.

Comment: You should enable html in axis labels - so the html tags will be rendered correctly https://jsfiddle.net/srduscea/1/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help!